# Apache configuration issues

Tags: apache-httpd, opensuse, wordpress

I'm running OpenSuSE Linux and installed `apache`, `php`, `mysql`, `vsftp` for web experiments.

I installed Wordpress on local Apache but... problem comes from here. So I've localhost/wordpress as root directory, which is `/srv/www/htdocs/wordpress/`
of course there is content directory and plugins and themes...

Wordpress can see installed plugins and themes, but doesn't see sub-directories of theme directory. So no images, nothing else what is in sub-directories isn't displayed. I 've checked, it isn't a theme issue.... something on Apache needs to be configured.

Comment: Have you looked in the apache error log ? /var/logs/... (there are variations depends on you config). So look at your config /etc/apache/httpd.conf etc to find the log files and then look in the logfile error.log for a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on the directories and sub-directories needs to be such that the user running Apache can access them, at a minimum readonly, plus the execution bits need to be enabled on *ALL* these directories so that Apache's user can access them too.

You'll likely want to run a command like so:

```
$ find /srv/www/htdocs/wordpress ! -user apache -ls
11141795    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 saml     saml         4096 Feb 21 15:42 .
6562124  752 -rw-rw-r--   1 saml     saml       766590 Dec  6 19:59 ./dsohowto.pdf
11141812    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 saml     saml           44 Feb 21 15:42 ./url.txt
```

This will identify any directories or files that are not owned by user `apache`. Which I'm using as a stand-in for whatever user happens to be the user that is designated for Apache.

```
$ grep ^User /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
User apache
```

You can see what groups the `apache` user might be a part of as well. Often times the "htdocs" directories will be grouped so that `apache` can see them instead of giving outright ownwership to the `apache` user.

*user*

```
$ getent group apache
apache:x:48:
```

*groups*

```
$ getent passwd apache
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/usr/share/httpd:/sbin/nologin
```